# Insert data into inputfield instead of textarea

Tags: javascript

I have a profile page, if i select a option from the dropdown the data will be inserted into the text area fields. But it doesn't work when i change my textarea type to input type.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // code to get all records from table via select box
    $("#profiel").change(function() {
        var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        var dataString = 'empid='+ id;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getProfile.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(employeeData) {
               if(employeeData) {
                    $("#heading").show();
                    $("#no_records").hide();
                    $("#artiestnaam").text(employeeData.artistname);
            $("#id").text(employeeData.id);
                    $("#records").show();
                } else {
                    $("#heading").hide();
                    $("#records").hide();
                    $("#no_records").show();
                }
            }
        });
    })
  });
```

**Doesn't work**

```
<input name="artiestnaam" placeholder="Artiestnaam" class="form-control" id="artiestnaam"></input>
```

**This DOES work but i don't want to use this**

```
<textarea name="artiestnaam" cols="1" placeholder="Artiestnaam" rows="1" style="resize:none;overflow:auto;background-color:white;" class="form-control" id="artiestnaam"></textarea>
```

I am curious what i am doing wrong with javascipt, i never use javascript(found this code online) so i apologise if this is a dumb question. Thanks for your time

Comment: Using the `text` method is wrong, use https://api.jquery.com/val/ (That is what you should have been using for the textarea already, it works for both.) And `</input>` is not a thing, `input` is a stand-alone element.

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: Also I would test the ID in case it is empty

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$("#artiestnaam").text(employeeData.artistname);
```

Do

```
$("#artiestnaam").val(employeeData.artistname);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can user below

```
 $("#artiestnaam").val(employeeData.artistname);
```

OR

```
$("#artiestnaam").attr('value',employeeData.artistname);
```

Instead of

```
 $("#artiestnaam").text(employeeData.artistname);
```